# How do I change Eclipse shift+enter in git commit message?

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse 4.4 (Luna) on Windows7.  When I commit a change to git I'd like to be able to insert a new line in the message...Normally I'd hit shift+enter but that submits the messsage.  So is there any way to add a newline to my git commit message?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and tried to search for a solution. Then a friend told my to try just "Enter" which worked as intended.. :)

So, skip shift-Enter/any other combination and just press Enter to insert a new line.